# How to fix the "connection fail" error for export-tsfile tool of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Does anyone know if the export-tsfile tool in Apache IoTDB needs to change any configuration when it reports that it cannot connect to the server? The error message is: "connect failed because Fail to reconnect to server. Please check server status." I checked that the IP port number, account name and password are not wrong. How should I fix this error then?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please